# ¿Como hago este programa?

Tags: java, if, bucle-for

Ingresar un conjunto de 20 personas y solamente contabilizar aquellos que tengan edad comprendida entre 18 y 45.

El problema es que no se como poner la condicion de contar edades entre 18 y 45.

```
    int personas = 21;
    int edadDe18A45 = 0;
    int edades = 0;
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

    for (int i = 1; i < personas; i++) {

        System.out.println(i + "Ingrese edad : ");
        edades = teclado.nextInt();

        if (17 < edades && edades > 44) { // No se si esta bien como puse la condicion en el if :/

            // Al poner esa condicion me cuenta edades de 18 hasta el 90 y mas...

            edadDe18A45++;
        }

    }

    System.out.println("Cantidad de personas con edad comprendida entre 18 y 45 años : " + edadDe18A45);
```

Comment: ehhh.. leamos.. 17 es menor que edades.. y edades es mayor a 44... o sea.. todos los mayores de 17? :p

Comment: jajaj lo que quise poner es :  si edades es mayor que 17 y edades es mayor que 44 , para que me cuente entre los numeros entre 18 y 45

Comment: o sea.. te diste cuenta de tu error?

Comment: 2.8 Toma de decisiones: operadores de igualdad y relacionales, en el libro de deitel.

Comment: Recuerda que siempre ante un problema en programación hay que poner mucha atención en lo que queremos lograr, en este caso queremos identificar que el número que vamos a evaluar sea mayor o igual a 18 y que sea menor o igual a 45 por lo tanto seria: `edades >= 18 && edades <= 45`

Comment: Ah ok , entonces en la condicion del if  primero pongo la variable en el que voy a ingresar los datos por teclado ? , por que yo pense que no importaba el orden @M.Gress

Comment: El orden no importa, todo depende de como coloques la condición pero para que sea mas legible tu código lo recomendable es colocarla tal cual suena, es común ver fallas en condicionales al ordenarlas de una manera particular. Como te indica @M.Gress

Comment: Más que el orden, siempre tenemos que entender lo que estamos haciendo, siempre lee tu código y ve si tiene sentido lo que estas escribiendo con lo que quieres lograr, la forma en que tu lo tienes se leria: Sí 17 es menor a edades y edades es mayo a 44 entonces... para esa condición estarias aceptando números que menores a 17 y mayores a 44 lo cual no tiene sentido ningun número puede cumplir esa condición. @computer96

Comment: Muchas Gracias a ambos, M.Gress  y Victor , voy a tener en cuenta lo que me dijieron :) , Saludos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amigo la única falla que tienes es en las condicionales, te recomiendo que amoldes tus condicionales de tal manera que al leerlas las puedas entender fácilmente:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int personas = 20;
        int edadDe18A45 = 0;
        int edades = 0;
        java.util.Scanner teclado = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
        for (int i = 1; i <= personas; i++) {
            System.out.println(i + "Ingrese edad : ");
            edades = teclado.nextInt();
            if (edades >= 18 && edades <= 45) {
                edadDe18A45++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Cantidad de personas con edad comprendida entre 18 y 45 años : " + edadDe18A45);
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias , ya funciona :D , Saludos!

Comment: De nada bro éxitos con tus proyectos.

Answer (score 0):

Piensa en una recta de números naturales.
Los números empiezan en el siguiente orden: 1,2,3,4,5... y así hasta el infinito y más allá.

Por lo tanto, si quieres hacer el rango de edades de los 18 a los 45 deberíamos tener el siguiente orden según las matemáticas: 18 <= edad <= 45.

En cuanto a programación, el término < no tiene en cuenta ese extremo, por lo que nuestro rango pasa a ser: 17 < edad < 46.

Por lo que en definitiva tu código debería quedar:

```
    int personas = 21;
    int edadDe18A45 = 0;
    int edades = 0;
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

    for (int i = 1; i < personas; i++) {

        System.out.println(i + "Ingrese edad : ");
        edades = teclado.nextInt();

        if (17 < edades && edades < 46) {
            edadDe18A45++;
        }

    }

    System.out.println("Cantidad de personas con edad comprendida entre 18 y 45 años : " + edadDe18A45);
```